# Creating model within partial razor page itself

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor

I am looking to rewrite an existing ASP.NET MVC application to .Net 5 Razor pages and one of the issues I am struggling to resolve is how to create a partial razor page that creates it's own model rather than having the model passed in from the parent page.

In MVC, I would simply add an action to the controller and specify this within the view;

```
@Html.Action("_SideNavigation", "Shared")
```

Ultimately, this would call the _SideNavigation action on the share controller, which would then create the model and pass it back to the view.

I am trying to achieve something similar in Razor Pages, I do not want to define the model of the partial within the model of the parent view, such as this;

```
<partial name="_Partial1" model="Model.PartialModel" />
```

I have tried creating an empty model within the parent page and assumed this would then call the OnGet() method within the partial itself;

```
<partial name="_Test" model="new _TestModel()" />

 public class _TestModel : PageModel
    {
        public TopNavigation TopNavigation {  get; set; } = new TopNavigation();


        public void OnGet()
        {
            TopNavigation = new TopNavigation { NotificationCount = 1 };
        }
    }
```

and then referencing the model in the page;

```
@Model.TopNavigation.NotificationCount
```

But it is always null.

Is this behaviour not available in razor pages?

Comment: Are you saying, you want a partial-view inside a parent view, to create a model that should not exist in the parent's model, but pass that model back to the parent so you can still use it?

Comment: Not quite, the partial and model for that partial need to be independent of the parent. I do not want the parent to supply the model.